# How do I make ADB work on x64?

Tags: android, usb, 64-bit, adb

I tried installing the Android USB driver on my x64 machine and it fails. Does Android development not support 64 bit Windows, or am I possibly doing something wrong?

Comment: I have it working on Vista x64, perhaps if you post the problem you are getting we can help.

Answer (score 2):

How does it fail? Following the instructions at the link below worked for me in Win7 x64.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing